# Stubbing @Immutable groovy classes using Spock

Tags: groovy, immutability, spock, stub

For instance I have a class

```
@Immutable
class User {
    String id
}
```

and I want to stub it in the way I used to stub java classes

```
def "should stub class"() {
    given:
    def validator = new BitSolutionValidator(eventBus)
    def student = GroovyStub(User)

    when:
    validator.onStudentHandedOverBitSolution(new StudentHandedOverBitSolutionEvent(
            student, GroovyStub(BitTask), GroovyStub(BitSolution)))

    then:
    student.id >> STUDENT_ID
}
```

But when the code executed I noticed student.id returned null. Is there a way to stub @Immutable groovy classes using Spock or I have to use metaClass?

Answer (score 1):

I've upgraded grails version to 2.4.3 and problem solved.

Comment: spock is at version 1.0 as of now

Comment: One presumes he means Grails 2.4.3